# Creating a QImage from QBytearray

Tags: java, c++, qt, bufferedimage, qimage

I'm trying to construct QImages from data saved as 16-bit integers in a binary file. I'm able to load the data in fine, but my program fails when I use the QImage::loadFromData(QBytearray ba) function (returning false) as follows:

```
QBytearray frame;
QImage pic = QImage(256, 256, QImage::Format_RGB888);

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        // Access value of pixel at each location
        datum = store[i][j];

        for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            // Calculate colour at given pixel
            col = (255.0f * ((float)datum - (float)min) / ((float)(max - min)));
            // Assign colour value to the pixel
            frame[c+3*j+3*i*width] = ((unsigned char)col);
        }
    }
}

pic.loadFromData(frame);
```

I repurposed this from Java code I had previously written which worked perfectly as intended (from the exact same data):

```
BufferedImage image = = new BufferedImage(256, 256, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

byte[] data = image.getRaster().getDataBuffer();

for (j=0; j<height; j++) {
    for (i=0; i<width; i++) {
        //Find value of the pixels at the location
        datum=data[j][i];
        for (c=0; c<3; c++) {
            //Calculate the colour at the given pixel
            col=(255.0f*((float)datum-(float)min)/((float)(max-min)));
            //Assign the colour value to the pixel
            data[c+3*i+3*j*width] = (byte)col;
        } 
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me to see where I'm getting this wrong? I've been stumped for days and am all out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried making `store` a hard-coded set of predetermined values? If so, what was the result? If not, could you do that and give us the result? What is `frame` when you finish building it?

Comment: @MirroredFate I can't really do that considering that the image is 256x256, so hard coding the values for that image is a bit time consuming.
And what do you mean exactly by what `frame` is when I've finished building it? Size?

Comment: One thing that has baffled me though is that dumping the Bytearray from a separate image loaded in directly from file (which works fine) gives me a QByteArray 2562 elements long - whereas the one I'm constructing is 196609 elements long. I feel this (huge) size discrepancy is at least part of the problem, but I don't know what the difference in the data formatting might be between the two. I mean, the 196609 byte array worked fine in the Java implementation, so I don't really know why the C++ bytearray for a same-sized image would be so much smaller.

Comment: Also, using the dumped QByteArray in the `QImage::loadFromData(QByteArray ba)` function works exactly as advertised. It seems as if the size discrepancy is the major issue, but even if I drop the colour setting (c `for` loop) I still have an array 65536 elements long.

Comment: *This is mainly guesses* You have a 2d array `store`, and a `QByteArray` frame. You are moving unsigned chars (1 byte) from the `store` to `frame`, but you need 3 bytes total for your RGB value. This means `frame` is essentially an array of bytes equal to 256*256*3, or 196609 bytes. I don't see where you are putting in header info to tell which kind of image it is, or any sort of meta characters to give the size...

Comment: That's why I was suggesting you fabricate a (simple) `frame` or `store`- just make it blue or something. Make a for loop that iterates 65536 times and adds character values of 0,0,255 on each iteration. Then maybe specify a couple different image types when you use `loadFromData` and see if any work.

Comment: A possible simple solution would be to use the [QImage constructor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-4) rather than loading, so you can specify the height and width. [You can get the const * char](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#constData), and specify the image type as "JPG" or something...

Comment: I've edited my post to reflect the formats of the respective image types. Due to the similarity of the argument types I thought that the classes would work in much the same way, but for some reason the QImage class needs a lot less data than the BufferedImage.
I just tried hardcoding the data and that hasn't been successful either.
I've tried loading the data in with differing format flags "PNG, JPG, BMP etc" and they haven't worked then or now. I've also tried just using the first 2562 elements of my generated array and that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, assuming that you are in fact trying to set RGB values for individual pixels, after reading the [QImage details](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#details), I see you can do it using the following:

```
value = qRgb(189, 149, 39); // 0xffbd9527
image.setPixel(1, 1, value);
```

So, something like:

```
QImage pic = QImage(256, 256, QImage::Format_RGB888);
QRgb value;
int r,b,g;

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        // Access value of pixel at each location
        datum = store[i][j];
        //I get really confused what is going on here... you don't seem to be actually using `c` for the calculation?
        for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++) { //let's just pretend you set the ints r,b,g in here somewhere
            // Calculate colour at given pixel
            col = (255.0f * ((float)datum - (float)min) / ((float)(max - min)));
        }
        // Assign colour value to the pixel
        value = qRgb(r, g, b);
        pic.setPixel(i, j, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked absolutely perfectly, thank you so much, this has been aggravating me for days. You have no idea how glad I am to have finally found a solution.